# Need to know build no using work item number in TFS

Tags: tfs

I have TFS server 2008.
When we select any paricular build we use to get the work items involved in that build.
I need to know in the reverse way i.e. if I know work item number then I can directly find the build number.
Any help will be great.

Comment: Are you asking if you can do this in TFS API or through the Team Explorer UI?

Comment: Hi NGM...Any thing available will be helpful.I just to need to get the objective

Answer (score 0):

From the Team Explorer UI, I don't believe there is a way to find a build by WI.

Using TFS API, I am sure you could build up a query to do this.  I know how to get all changesets that are associated with a WI and from there I am sure you can build it up to find all builds associated with a changeset.